# Get all checkbox of datatable with pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get all the checked checkbox in the datatable with multiple pages, but when I get the checkbox of the other pages, it says that those are null. Like is they only exists when the page is active.

I have tried using Jquery, but only write the ones in the active page even when there are checkbox selected in other pages.

JQuery

```
var chekeados =  $("input[name='aprovacion']:checked");
 console.log(chekeados);
```

Here I create the table and appends the checkbox

JS

```
function createTable () {
    for (i = 0; i < ordersList.length; i++) {

       $tblRow.append('<td id="td' + i + '">' + ' <input  onclick="calcPlant('+i+')" id="check'+ i +'"type="checkbox" name="approve" value="'+ i +'">' + '</td>');

        $('#ID_DATATABLE').append($tblRow);

    }

$('#ID_DATATABLE').DataTable({});
}
```

Here is the function used to get all checkbox, and get it enters the if

JS

```
 for (k = 0; k < ordersList.length; k++){
    var checkBox = document.getElementById('check'+k);

    if (checkBox.checked == true){
       console.log("hello");
    }
  }
```

What I need is to get all checkbox that are checked in all the data table.